# Coding and decoding - ISSUE and DATES

Tags: mathematics, letters

> If the word ISSUE is written as 341145, how is DATES written as?

The answer is:

> 4120519

In the case of ISSUE, I get the logic as the product of the place values of all the letters: ISSUE = 9 × 19 × 19 × 21 × 5 = 341145. In the case of DATES, the product turns out to be 4 × 1 × 20 × 5 × 19 = 7600. The two answers don't agree with each other.

I can't see any other logic by which the desired number can be obtained.

Comment: Your 2nd answer is correct, suggested one from somewhere is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question? Where did you get that answer from? If you give us a link to see it, we may be able to explain what went wrong.

Comment: The given answer for DATES is just the concatenation of the A1Z26 encoding (4,1,20,5,19), which is completely different to the encoding for ISSUE. Where did you get this question from?

Comment: @bobble I am a part of a WhatsApp forum where they send questions like these. So I am not wholly sure of the source.

Comment: Also, are you asking what the correct answer is, or for us to justify the other answer?

Comment: Both - how is that answer justified, and what is the correct answer

Comment: @fljx if DATES is concatenation of A1Z26 encoding, how is it that ISSUE is not written as (9,19,19,21,5)?

Comment: @HarikrishnanM I don't know, it's your question. I'm just pointing out the trivial explanation for what you've given as the expected answer. I don't see how anyone could possibly guess the expected encoding for DATES from the given answer for ISSUE, which is why I commented rather than answering.

Comment: Correct 21 in your 2nd product to 19. Product should be applied for both words or not any, don't you agree?

Comment: @z100, noted and corrections done.

Comment: Well, now you can see 4 1 20 5 19.

Comment: @z100 that aside, if we follow the same logic for the ISSUE, it should be written as 9 19 19 21 5. Which doesn't look similar to 341145.

So, it should be only the product logic?

Comment: Product almost never looks similar to a sequence of its factors. Yes, simply only 1st step applied, product is missing.

Comment: I just googled this question and found the same on several websites where the correct answer is given to be 7600. One for example: https://byjus.com/question-answer/in-a-certain-code-language-issue-is-written-as-341145-in-the-same-code-language/